# Sending the log file using a 'Send Mail Task' from the OnError handler fails

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a package which is configured to create a log file. When an error occurs, I want the OnError event handler for the package to send an email with the log file as an attachement. This fails with the message:

> Either the file "C:\Log\blablabla.txt" does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file.

The file does exist, so the problem must be that I do not have permissions to access it. The package is able to create the file so does this mean the file cannot be accessed because the package is still executing (and therefore writing to the file)?

**Configuration:**
SQL-Server 2005.
Property DelayValidation == True.

**Edit:** I have stumbled across a solution for this problem. It is not enough to set DelayValidation of the task itself to True. You must also set it for the Event Handler (OnError in this case) that contains the task. Doing the same thing for a Send Mail Task that is executed when the package succeeds (so from within Control Flow) still produces the same error.

Comment: I strongly suspect the issue is that the file is in use and therefore unable to be picked up by the Send Mail Task. If I can get some time, I'll try and reproduce. As an alternative, if you are running the package via SQL Agent, you can use the alerts from there to pick up the file. Or, if you're using a parent-child paradigm, let the parent's event handler pick up the child's log, assuming they are using separate logs.

Comment: How do you create the log file in your package? Using a file connection or writing the code in the script task?

Answer (score 0):

For sending attachments through send email task you should have sysadmin permission.

Comment: Can you share a link to a page on MSDN which talks about this?